# The best way for REST client to communicate with REST server?

Tags: node.js, rest, architecture

I'm trying to divide my app to one REST client which shows screens and one REST server which provides API data. Since I'm new to this architecture, I want to make sure if I'm going for the right way.

For REST client, I use ReactJS with Node.js for server-side rendering.
For REST server, I use Django with Django REST Framework for API.

I use the below configuration so that I can redirect API requests starting with `/api` to the REST server. However, by doing that, I feel like the API request doesn't respond right away even though I'm using server-side rendering(The screen shows up and then data from API server shows up about a second later.

Am I doing the right way? Is the delay just because of my API server's progressing time?

```
const api = express()
app.use("/api", proxy({ target: "http://apiserver.com", changeOrigin: true }));
```

Comment: To clarify further: From where do you call that rest api? Your Frontend (React) or backend (Node)?

Comment: To use server-side rendering in React, I'm using Node.js which means that I have 
a client server (Node.js) and a API server (Django).